# Form with multiple fieldsets. Need to hide/show ONLY next textarea onClick, not all hidden textareas

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a from with fieldsets that consist of "yes" "no" radio buttons. I need "no" to reveal a hidden textarea in it's own fieldset, but i can only get it to reveal all the hidden textareas in all fieldsets.
This is what i was going for, but it does not work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".failRadio").click(function(){
         var nextTextArea = $(this).next().find(".describe");
         $(nextTextArea).show(500);
      });
  });



            <fieldset>
                <legend>One</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="pass">Pass</label>
                        <input id="pass" name="foo1" type="radio">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="fail">Fail</label>
                        <input id="fail" name="foo1" type="radio" class="failRadio" />
                    </li>
                    <li><textarea style="display: none;" class="describe">Describe:</textarea></li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Two</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="pass">Pass</label>
                        <input id="pass" name="foo1" type="radio">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="fail">Fail</label>
                        <input id="fail" name="foo1" type="radio" class="failRadio" />
                    </li>
                    <li><textarea style="display: none;" class="describe">Describe:</textarea></li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(".failRadio").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('ol').find(".describe").show(500);
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much! That is more the approach i was going for. (i don't have enough rep to upvote, btw)

Comment: Not an issue. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go up one level to the `li` tag before getting its sibling:

```
var nextTextArea = $(this).parent().next().find(".describe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$(".failRadio").on('click', function(){
    $('textarea').hide(500);
    $(this).parent().next().find("textarea").show(500);
});
```

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6xy72/)**